# Can't get animations to work with md-tab-nav-bar/md-tab-link

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-animations

I switched from `MdTabGroup` to the `md-tab-nav-bar`/`md-tab-link` directives in order to be able to assign routes to individual tab pages. Unfortunately though, I lost the slide-in animation in the process (there appears to be no animation for the directive), so I tried to mimic the behavior from `MdTab` with no success so far.

Here's the template using the tab directives:

```
<div class="ink-results" *ngIf="model && (model | async).length > 0" >
    <nav md-tab-nav-bar>
        <a md-tab-link
            *ngFor="let browser of model | async;trackBy: trackByBrowserId"
            [routerLink]="['/results', browser.id]"
            routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
            [active]="rla.isActive">
            {{browser.name}}
        </a>
    </nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

and here's the template that is routed to:

```
<div class="ink-explorer">
    <div class="ink-items">
        <div class="ink-item"
            [@flyInOut]="state"
            *ngFor="let result of results | async;trackBy: trackById"
            routerLinkActive="ink-active-item">
            <a [routerLink]="[result.id]">
                <md-icon svgIcon="flask" 
                    [ngClass]="{ 'ink-failed': (result.status === 2), 'ink-pending': result.status === 4, 'ink-success': result.status === 6 }">
                </md-icon>
                <div class="ink-item-title">{{result.description}}</div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ink-preview">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

The animation (`flyInOut`) itself is working perfectly (tested in different projects) and is executed once when the first tab is selected

```
http://localhost:3000/results/<tab1>
```

If I click on the second tab after, I navigate to

```
http://localhost:3000/results/<tab2>
```

alright but there is no transition/animation at all. I figure that is because I have exactly one `state` inside the component and there is only one instance of that component and thus only this single state.

I'm wondering what I can do about that, I'd like to have that slide in/out animation for my tabs again. The whole project can be found [here](https://github.com/erasethis/instant-karma) if that is any help.

Comment: got same problem, did you figured out a fix?

Comment: Same question, did you find a way to make it work?

Comment: Check out https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-supercharge-your-router-transitions-using-new-animation-features-v4-3-3eb341ede6c8.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the article of [Angular — Supercharge your Router transitions using animations](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-supercharge-your-router-transitions-using-new-animation-features-v4-3-3eb341ede6c8) you can create your own routing animations.

Using the same reference, I have created a sample code on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-po4uyy).

Key things to note:

1. You will need to import `BrowserAnimationsModule` in your module
2. `router.animations.ts` - To handle animations based on the state of the route. These animations are based on `state` (which is number, 1 for the first router, 2 for the second router and so on.) of the route, which is defined in `routes` constant in `main.ts` file. You would notice, I have used `:increment` and `:decrement` in `transitions`'s `stateChangeExpr`, like below:

   ```
   transition(':decrement', [...]), // if state-number is decremented, this animation will be performed
   transition(':increment', [...]) // if state-number is incremented, this animation will be performed
   ```

   The reason to do like above is to handle all tabs transitions dynamically based on their state numbers. So that, we don't have to handle each transition/animation separately for all routes/tabs.
3. Trigger animation on route change - `tab-nav-bar-basic-example.html`, like below:

```html
<main [@routerTransition]="getState(o)">
    <router-outlet #o="outlet"></router-outlet>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

shhdharmen solution is great, I just made some improvements based on angular 15.

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar [tabPanel]="tabPanel">
  <a
    mat-tab-link
    *ngFor="let item of notificationMenu; let i = index"
    routerLinkActive="navbar__link_active"
    [routerLink]="['/', item.routerLink]"
    [active]="index === i"
    (click)="index = i">
    {{ item.title }}
  </a>
</nav>

<main [@routerTransition]="tabPanel">
  <router-outlet #tabPanel></router-outlet>
</main>
```

I get rid from getState() function, it is now unnecessary